# Does it matter for SEO which keyword is first in the URL path?

Tags: seo, url, keywords, path

Does it really matter in SEO if my URL is:

- `https://example.com/test/18-apr-2019/author`
- `https://example.com/18-apr-2019/test/author`
- `https://example.com/author/test/18-apr-2019`

Does it really matters which keyword comes first? As you can see URLs have the same keywords as parameters. But does it really matter which one is first and which last?

Will any of the above examples affect the way Google indexes and displays my page?

Comment: See also: [Are keywords in URLs good SEO or needlessly redundant?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/47342/are-keywords-in-urls-good-seo-or-needlessly-redundant)

Comment: You may also find this helpful [For SEO should you primarily optimize for “<city> <service>” or “<service> in <city>”?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/111275/for-seo-should-you-primarily-optimize-for-city-service-or-service-in-c)